# function argument should be type of one of the object's key type

Tags: typescript

In Typescript,
I have a function:-

```
   function updateSetting(settingName, settingValue: string[]| number | null) { 
      this.props.updateSetting({[settingName]}: settingValue)
  }
```

and i also have a object, so i have an interface for it

```
   interface Setting {
      names: string[]
      city: string | null
      age: number
   }
```

So, i want to use object as an argument, and i also want that one of the property of the object is passed as an argument which is decided at the run time. So in my function settingName can be either 'name' or 'city' or 'age', so i want to assign the type from the interface itself.

I don't want to write (`settingValue: string[]| number | null)` i want to write something like

```
settingValue: valueof Setting
```

because setting value can be any of the type `names, city, age`.

How can i achieve this in typescript ?

Comment: Take a look at `keyof`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html. It looks like it could fit your use case

Answer (score 3):

if you want to set type of settingValue and your interface dynamicaly you can try:

```
settingValue: Setting[keyof Setting]; // string[]| number | null
```

or if you want keys of setting it without their types:

```
settingValue = keyof Setting ; // names| city | age
```

Answer (score 3):

You can improve your function more then just the type of `settingValue` you can also ensure the `settingName` and `settingValue` are consistent:

```
function updateSetting<TKey extends keyof Setting>(settingName: TKey, settingValue: Setting[TKey]) {
    //...
}

interface Setting {
    names: string[]
    city: string | null
    age: number
}

updateSetting("names", [""])
updateSetting("age", [""]) //error
```

We use the `keyof` operator to specify that the generic parameter `Tkey` must be a string literal type that is one of te keys of `Setting` then we specify that `settingValue` must have whatever type the field of `Setting` has for the given key using a type query `Setting[TKey]`

This approach ensures more type safety if you use it with constant keys usually. If you want to pass an arbitrary string you will need to use a type assertion, and the type of `settingValue` will be the same as `Setting[keyof Setting]`:

```
let str;
updateSetting(str as keyof Setting, 0) //ok
updateSetting(str as keyof Setting, new Date()) //error
```

Comment: This was exceptionally helpful. I had no idea how to google this, but stumbled across this answer and it's perfect.